# Can the jquery dataTables plugin respect alternate row colors after sorting/filtering?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, datatables, styling

I am using [jquery datatables plugin](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html) which seems like a useful plugin to take a regular html table and add sorting, filtering, paging, etc

One issue i see is that when i search it doesn't seem to update the "odd" / "even" row classes so if my table has 100 rows but when i filter it has 10 it might be that all 10 are the same backcolor or 8 are the same backcolor

I see the same issue after i sort by a column as well where it might "bunch up" a bunch of rows with teh same backcolor after I sort by a column.

Is there anyway that the datatables plugin can reapply even/odd styling after the filter so no matter what you are filtering, there is always alternate row backcolor?

Comment: This functionality is available by default, see [Default styling options](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes). Are you sure you're using `display` class or at least `stripe` class for `<table>`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to hold after filtering rows

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your page or example on JSFiddle demonstrating the problem? What version of DataTables are you using? What are your DataTables initialization options?

Comment: Second the request for code example. DataTables definitely updates the striping on redraws. Sounds like maybe you're handling the filtering externally from the plugin in which case you'd definitely have issues. Can't help without seeing code, though

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### CAUSE

This functionality is available by default. Most likely the reason for this unusual behavior:

- you override `odd` and `even` classes in your CSS, or
- your code affects table structure after filtering

#### SOLUTION #1

1. [**Default styling**](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html) or [**jQuery UI**](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html) or [**Foundation**](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/foundation.html)

   Use class `display` for your `<table>` as shown below. See [Default styling options](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes) for a list of all available classes.

   ```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   ```

   See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onsr5sfz/) for demonstration.
2. [**Bootstrap**](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

   Use classes `table table-striped table-bordered` for your `<table>` as shown below:

   ```
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   ```

   See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxk6o3xm/) for demonstration.

#### SOLUTION #2

If there is a CSS rule that overrides `odd` and `even` classes you can instruct jQuery DataTables to use alternative classes instead with [`stripeClasses`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/stripeClasses) option.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "stripeClasses": [ 'odd-row', 'even-row' ]
} );
```

Comment: The Bootstrap solution was a great fix for me. I'm glad to see that with jQuery Datatables.

Answer (score 18):

To archive this you have to use [Base style - no styling classes](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/no-classes.html) `datatable`
to do this just remove datatable classes from `table` `tag`

After this create your own classes for `odd` (e.g `myodd` ) and `even`(e.g `myeven` ) rows.

now the next task is to apply these classes to the table rows on each table draw means:

**1.** When filters are applied

**2.** When limit of visible records is changed etc.

To do this datatabe provides `rowCallback()` you can use this in this way:

```
 $('#myTabel').dataTable({
        "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
            if(index%2 == 0){
                $(row).removeClass('myodd myeven');
                $(row).addClass('myodd');
            }else{
                $(row).removeClass('myodd myeven');
                 $(row).addClass('myeven');
            }
          }
    });
```

Please Note:

To avoid `!important` in `css rule` define `css rule` for `odd`, `even` rows like this:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.myeven{
    background-color:#f2dede;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr.myodd{
    background-color:#bce8f1;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/4za80xky/

Comment: This functionality is available by default, see [Base style](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html), there is no need to use `rowCallback` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

My this comment is applicable for **how to REMOVE or MODIFY Jquery Datatable Row classes**

Datatables now provide an optional json parameter named as defined for its [1.10+ documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stripeClasses#Example).

so if you want to **completely remove odd even classes** then use the following parameter during tables initialization.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "stripeClasses": [] //Empty Array.
} );
```

so **if you want to apply custom css class on every row of Datatables** then.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "stripeClasses": ['yourRowClass']
} );
```

If you want to **apply more than 1 css class (in odd even or sequential manner)** such that these classes will repeat them-self on after every nth row is completed then use this

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "stripeClasses": [ 'strip1', 'strip2', 'strip3' ] //This combination will repeat always 3rd row
} );
```

**DataTables will apply each class sequentially, looping when required.**

Answer (score 1):

***It worked for me.....***

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.even{
    background-color:lightgray;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr.odd{
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had to expand on the above solution. I am allowing the user to adjust the stripe color, so I had to do:

```
rowCallback: (row, data, index) => {
  const stripeColor = this.options.stripeColor;

  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    $(row).removeClass('odd-row even-row');
    $(row).addClass('odd-row');

    if (!!this.options.stripe) {
      $(row).css({ background: 'transparent' })
    }
  } else {

    $(row).removeClass('odd-row even-row');
    $(row).addClass('even-row');

    if (!!this.options.stripe) {
      $(row).css({ background: stripeColor })
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery DataTable defines "odd" and "even" rows by default with the same class names, so you can use these classes to set your custom CSS like below:

```
table tbody tr.even{
    background-color: #8882;
}

table tbody tr.odd{
    background-color: #8881;
} 

table tbody tr:hover{
    background-color: #8883;
}
```

Enjoy...